# What is the black piece on the utility sink?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

What's this black piece on the utility sink, and can it be replaced?

It leaks like crazy when the water is on and makes a mess.  I would like to replace it but I need some good keywords to search for videos on how to do so.

[image]

EDIT: Added another picture with the black ring moved

[image]

Comment: `I would like to replace it` ... why would you want to do that? ... just remove it

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if this thing has value.  I think it's a vacuum breaker after more Googling

Comment: yes, it is a vacuum breaker ... but it is a manual version ... it will not function as a vacuum breaker if it is closed and water pressure drops

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be (half of) a laundry or dishwasher hose quick-disconnect adapter. The other half would be on the mating hose. Perhaps it left with the people that used to own the house, since you don't recognize it?

They normally attach where the **aerator** goes, and if you are not using something that attaches a hose there, you can just remove it (unscrew) and replace with a stock aerator. Depending on faucet, no aerator (*i.e.* just remove it) may also be acceptable.

Given the rubber part, it *may* just pull off and not actually be screwed in place at all. An unscrewing motion combined with pulling should get it, either way it's attached. All the ones I've personally used screwed in place.

Comment: I just saw some faint writing that said push up to drain so I did.  I added a new picture.  Does this change or confirm the answer?

Comment: Nope, just unscrew the whole thing, @jglouie. Unless you need that fitting for the washer or other purpose, just get rid of it. Toss it in the garbage/recycling.

Comment: The new picture looks less like a quick-disconnect, but still like you just unscrew it and it stops being a leaky problem.